# C++/CLI - C# Interop - string conversion memory leak

Tags: c#, c++-cli, interop

I need to expose some existing .NET logic (i.e. assembly MyManaged.dll) to native code, so I've decided to create C++/CLI *bridge*. I've created C++/CLI project and added an reference to MyManaged.dll. Long story in short - it works - I've succeeded to access everything that should be accessible form native code.

But **big issue** is that my implementation leaks memory. After days of testing and researching I've narrowed problem down to `System::String` <-> `const wchar_t` conversion. Finally I've created a trivial C++/CLI project that demonstrates (reproduces) the issue:

```
#define EXPORTED __declspec(dllexport)

System::String^ ToManaged(const wchar_t* unmanagedString)
{
    return gcnew System::String(unmanagedString);
}

const wchar_t* ToUnmanaged(System::String^ managedString)
{
    return (wchar_t*) System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni(managedString).ToPointer();
}

EXPORTED const wchar_t* __stdcall GetString(const wchar_t* dummy)
{
    return ToUnmanaged(ToManaged(dummy));
}
```

(If it isn't obvious from the previous code - I'm pretty new in C++/CLI)

As I've mentioned the code works but accumulates memory consumption so there's definitely a leak in `System::String` <-> `const wchar_t` conversion.

My question is obvious: how to implement string conversion **without** the leak.

Thanks!

Comment: I would use COM and COM enable the methods you need to access. Use tlb.exe to generate the COM interop. Many less headaches. I went down the cli/c++ path and discovered issues like dll load order problems and virus software creating issues.

Comment: @CKIsLearning - Thanks for trying to help. Honestly, for some reason I'm pretty anti-COM oriented. I would go there if I haven't found any other solution, but since meanwhile I've solved the issue there's no reason to do so. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Every call to Marshal::StringToHGlobalUni() **must** be paired with a call to Marshal::FreeCoTaskMem().  That makes your ToUnmanaged() function broken without hope of a simple fix, that call isn't going to happen.  You'll have to re-think this, consider a smarter string type like std::wstring

Comment: @HansPassant - thanks but as you can see below I've already solved this by using `<msclr\marshal.h>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Please ignore negative voter - as you can see he even refused to explain what is wrong here. Different people have different motives... One thing is for sure: **solution provided here works perfectly, without any memory leak.**

I've found the solution (based on [Overview of Marshaling in C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx) and [marshal_context::marshal_as](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384856.aspx)). So the following should be changed:

```
#include <msclr\marshal.h>

System::String^ ToManaged(const wchar_t* unmanagedString)
{
    return msclr::interop::marshal_as<System::String^>(unmanagedString);
}

gcroot<msclr::interop::marshal_context^> context;

const wchar_t* ToUnmanaged(System::String^ managedString)
{        
    msclr::interop::marshal_context^ unpacked = context;

    if (unpacked != nullptr)
        delete unpacked;

    context = gcnew msclr::interop::marshal_context();

    return context->marshal_as<const wchar_t*>(managedString);
}
```

**NOTE:** Here I've implemented very clumsy handling of `marshal_context` instance - when the next call arrives, the result from the previous call is deleted. This implementation would fall apart in multi-threading scenario, so you should implement a better one having the following in mind:

- `marshal_context` instance can be used for multiple calls, but it should be deleted every now and then (to free the memory from previously marshaled strings);
- As soon as `marshal_context` is deleted - all `const wchar_t*` crated by using it are also deleted. It means that you should not delete context immediately after using it, but you need to provide enough time for calling code to actually get the resulting string.

Comment: It would be nice if one who down-voted this can provide some explanation. I can confirm that the solution provided works like charm, without any leaks.

Comment: I would guess you earned that downvote due to that brittle `marshal_context` handling, so *"works like charm"* is pretty relative...

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski - The point of the answer is not in copy-paste-using the same exact code sample, but in the approach that should be used - `<msclr\marshal.h>`. And this approach **does work like charm** (I'm already using it in production with 20,000 calls per second without any memory leak). About the code sample - I've already told everything in the answer, and provided some hints about how to implement it *correctly*.

Comment: But, at the end of the day, it is not important anymore. My aim here is not to collect points (obviously), but to get help when I need it, and to share what I've learned with others. Negative vote does not make damage to me, but to future visitors who may skip perfectly valid answer because of false negative vote.

Answer (score 0):

You need to free the pointer from `StringToHGlobalUni` after you've used it. Use `Marshal.FreeHGlobal` or `LocalFree`.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! But this hasn't helped (I've already tried).

Comment: To be more precise: In one of my previous attempts to resolve the issue I've implemented a logic that frees all `IntPtr` created this way after some time, but it didn't help.

Comment: Or to be even more precise: it may be an issue, but it is not the only issue for sure.

Answer (score 0):

While not built to your exact api, I think this addresses the memory

```
HRESULT GetString(BSTR* p_bstrResult, unsigned long* ulErrCode)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    try
    {
        System::String ^systemstring = gcnew System::String("");
                    DotNetObject::o = gcnew  DotNetObject:: DotNetObjectComponent();
        *ulErrCode = (unsigned long)o->GetString(systemstring); 
        pin_ptr<const wchar_t> wch = PtrToStringChars(systemstring);
        _bstr_t bstrt(wch);
        *p_bstrResult = bstrt.GetBSTR(); // native client babysits
        delete systemstring;        
    }
    catch(Exception ^ ex)
    {

    }   
    return hr;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! Meanwhile I've found the solution (as you can see in my answer). I'm not sure if your solution will also work, but it looks more complicated than the one I've found. Thanks anyway!